# JS and Firefox scratchpad

Tags: javascript, scratchpad

I'm using [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) to learn JS and I use [scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Tools/Scratchpad) to try some examples.

If I write

```
console.log('The value of b is ' + b);
var b;
```

Why does console.log say "The value of b is -1" ?! It should be undefined

Comment: On what page were you opening the scratchpad? Likely it did define a global variable with the value `-1`. Notice that when you take away the `var b;` declaration, the output won't change (or does it?).

Comment: You are right it's the same even when I remove var b;
I open it using Firefox

Comment: Yes, Firefox, but don't you have any tabs open? Also try `console.log(window)` and show us what you get

Answer (score 0):

Probably you defined the `var b` before with the value `-1`.

If you try the above code, you will see that, if the variable is already instantiated and if you declare again the variable without set any value to them, the variable it will not be instantiated.

```js
var b = -1;
console.log(b)
var b;
console.log(b)
```

Comment: You are right, and I agree with you, but I have nothing in the code that would make b = -1 !!
take a look at the picture : https://ibb.co/jzkNwa

Comment: Have you try close the browser and open it again? Sometimes, when you test things in the console, even if you refresh the browser, the variables will be sill on the memory

Comment: Yes, same results :(

Comment: Have you sure that is the only file that is been imported in the html?

Comment: I'm sure 100% .. the only thing on the page is what mentioned in the question and this only happens when I try scratchpad, If I write it in HTML file and run it, it works just fine.

Comment: Just the last thing, did you tried clean all data from the webpage (like cache, cookies, webstorage..) ?